# PHP: Print to windows-connected printer (SAMBA share)

Tags: php, printing, samba

Is it possible to print to a samba shared printer from php?

Printer works fine when sending a printer test jo. it's connected to a windows machine on smb://192.168.1.6/PRINTER

What i'm trying to do is:

```
$handle = printer_open("smb://192.168.1.6/PRINTER");
printer_write($handle, $file);
printer_close($handle);
```

But i'm not even receiving an FALSE or error message.

I've also tried:

```
$handle = printer_open("\\\\192.168.1.6\\PRINTER");
printer_write($handle, $file);
printer_close($handle);
```

With se same results.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks!